# Compute $\int xy dx +(x+y)dy$ over the curve $Γ$, $Γ$ is the arc $AB$ in the 1st quadrant of the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ from $A(1,0)$ to $B(0,1)$.

Tags: integration, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Compute $\int xydx+(x+y)dy$ over the curve $Γ$, where $Γ$ is the arc $AB$ in the first quadrant of the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ from $A(1,0)$ to $B(0,1)$.

I solved this problem  with the help of Green's theorem. My result is $\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{3}$. But the book I'm following, shows, the result is $\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{6}$. Since I'm a learner,  I don't understand where have I done the mistake.
Can anyone please give the solution?

Comment: If you typed up your work, we could see where your mistake was. But I suspect you used Greens theorem incorrectly. You can only use it with closed curves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your book is correct. First of all, your application of Green's theorem here is incorrect, as indicated in the comment. You can't apply Green's theorem for a curve that's not **simple closed**. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem. So the correct answer is through the line integral evaluation as follows

$$\int_\Gamma xydx+(x+y)dy=\int_{AB} xydx+(x+y)dy$$ $$=\int_{y=0}^1\bigg[y\sqrt{1-y^2}d\bigg(\sqrt{1-y^2}\bigg)+\bigg(\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\bigg)dy\bigg]$$ $$=-\int_0^1y^2dy+\int_0^1\sqrt{1-y^2}dy+\int_0^1ydy=-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{6}$$